# Referring to table fields in subform, in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, subform

I've made a simple database in ms access - made few tables, queries and so on.
I also made a form and a subform inside that form.
Subform contains a **table** with 1 column. The idea is - user inputs data in the table, then based on his typings, query runs, and produces data. Easy as that.

To make my life easier I've set up a simple function to save files as *.csv's. (also - I'm pretty new to VBA).

```
Function SaveAsCsv()

tExportName = "C:\Users\xxx" & Format(Date, "_mm\_dd\_yyyy") & ".csv"

DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "Mass_Extract_data", tExportName, True

End Function
```

And now, after few runs I see there is a need to do a little enhancing, so here's my question:

How can I refer to the table field inside a subform in vba?
Any help will be appreciated,

If you need more info, feel free to ask

Comment: Try `MainFormName!SubformName.Form![Control Name].`

Comment: Ok, seems like I managed to access the table contents:

`Me.Textbox.Value = Me.SubformNameTable_Form![Field]`

Thanks for help Kostas :)

Comment: Can this be done without bang notation? I'm seeing errors when using `.Fields.Item`